# View flipping on focus lost if windowSoftInputMode is adjustpan

Tags: android, listview, window-soft-input-mode, adjustpan

I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to get an EditText placed above softkeyboard without changing existing layout. The whole Activity gets pushed upwards until EditText is right above the keyboard. The EditText is placed inside a ListView.
When I leave the EditText by touching somewhere else in ListView, the keyboard starts closing.

The problem is: **During keyboards closing animation**, the whole ListView gets pushed up even more, just to move again down just a second later when the keyboard is fully closed. Thats annoying because of unneeded **up-/down flipping**.

I'm almost sure this happens because the ListView catches focus after EditText lost it, causing keyboard to try to pan the whole ListView above itself. But it shouldn't, because it got already a "close keyboard" command.

How can I force the keyboard to ignore any new "adjustPan" during it's closing process?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204230/soft-keyboard-push-up-hidding-action-bar-or-overlay-edittext

Comment: This don't seems to be related to topic. I just want to avoid the second/extra/wrong-direction panning during keyboard closing